# Several request to Google AI platform simultaneously

Tags: wordpress, machine-learning, web-applications, google-prediction, google-ai-platform

I am developing a website in wordpress that uses Google  AI platform predictions. The prediction request is done through the PHP client library.

Now my question is when several users from a website are making a prediction request simultaneously is Google’s Client library able to return the right prediction to each user?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that is the intended behavior, each response is linked to a particular request and thus responses should not be mixed up even if several requests are made simultaneously. I would recommend you to look at some AI Predictions official documentation like:

- [Prediction overview](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/overview)
- [Getting online predictions](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict)

In general, you should ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face (see, stack overflow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). Hence, try to implement your desired behavior and if you find any problems while doing so (e.g. responses are not properly assigned to each user) then let us know and we will try to help you.

In this case, if you find a clear issue with the Google prediction products you can open a [public issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui) or contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs) so the Google team tackles it accordingly.